# ClickHouse The memory is not auto release when an error occurs

Tags: memory, clickhouse

An error occurred when I move the data, but after the memory never auto release

SQL
INSERT INTO data_center.local_table SELECT * FROM data_center.base_table where create_time >= 1667664000 AND create_time < 1667750400

AND error message
Received exception from server (version 21.8.2): Code: 241. DB::Exception: Received from casd2412asdas.clickhouse.myid.com:9000. DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 55.47 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4718592 bytes), maximum: 55.47 GiB: While executing SinkToOutputStream. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED)

Then I tried to observe the memory. i use clickhouse-clinet

SELECT
*,
formatReadableSize(value)
FROM system.asynchronous_metrics
WHERE (metric LIKE '%Cach%') OR (metric LIKE '%Mem%')
ORDER BY metric ASC
FORMAT PrettyCompactMonoBlock

```
┌─metric───────────────────────┬───────value─┬─formatReadableSize(value)─┐
│ CompiledExpressionCacheBytes │       49152 │ 48.00 KiB                 │
│ CompiledExpressionCacheCount │          10 │ 10.00 B                   │
│ MMapCacheCells               │           0 │ 0.00 B                    │
│ MarkCacheBytes               │   356803712 │ 340.27 MiB                │
│ MarkCacheFiles               │       38894 │ 37.98 KiB                 │
│ MemoryCode                   │   366669824 │ 349.68 MiB                │
│ MemoryDataAndStack           │ 87388315648 │ 81.39 GiB                 │
│ MemoryResident               │ 56737828864 │ 52.84 GiB                 │
│ MemoryShared                 │   267223040 │ 254.84 MiB                │
│ MemoryVirtual                │ 92213809152 │ 85.88 GiB                 │
│ OSMemoryAvailable            │  8797671424 │ 8.19 GiB                  │
│ OSMemoryCached               │  4891324416 │ 4.56 GiB                  │
│ OSMemoryFreePlusCached       │  9688956928 │ 9.02 GiB                  │
│ OSMemoryFreeWithoutCached    │  4797632512 │ 4.47 GiB                  │
│ OSMemoryTotal                │ 66174210048 │ 61.63 GiB                 │
│ UncompressedCacheBytes       │  6871911688 │ 6.40 GiB                  │
│ UncompressedCacheCells       │       60288 │ 58.88 KiB                 │
└──────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

OSMemoryAvailable will never up.

Can I free memory manually ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, once allocated the ClickHouse process will not return system memory.  ClickHouse in general will use up to 90% of the detected system RAM based on the config.xml setting max_server_memory_usage_to_ram_ratio (which defaults to .9)

The actual memory used by ClickHouse at any time is internally tracked and will be freed when queries complete either normally or by exception. So the error message you are seeing:

> DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 55.47 GiB
> (attempt to allocate chunk of 4718592 bytes), maximum: 55.47 GiB:
> While executing SinkToOutputStream. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED)

indicates that whatever queries, merges, and mutations are currently executing are actually using 55+ GB.  You should check the `system.processes` table to determine what operations are consuming your memory at the time of the error message.

Comment: In fact, moving data in a day-by-day range. Finally, ranges of the same size cannot be moved

Comment: Is it related to about MVTable TO local_table ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM system.processes always only "SELECT * FROM system.processes"  itself